# How to see PUT Request

Tags: php, json, curl

Hi I'm trying to integrate with an API. I've been having some issues with this so I've been in contact with the support department.

They've asked me to "capture the entire request JSON". To be honest I'm not sure how to do this I've done a bit of research and I've tried  curl_getinfo($session) which gives me information but not what I'm looking for.

Here's the curl code I'm using.  Is there anyway I can get the request JSON to print to the screen?

```
    $session = curl_init();

    $putData = tmpfile();

    $jsonString = $params;

    fwrite($putData, $jsonString);

    fseek($putData, 0);

    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    // Do you want CURL to output the headers? Set to FALSE to hide them
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, true); 
    // pass the URL to CURL
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    // Tell CURL we are using PUT
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_PUT, true);
    // Now we want to tell CURL the were the file is and it's size
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_INFILE, $putData);
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_INFILESIZE, strlen($jsonString));
    // right all done? Lets execute this

    $output = curl_exec($session);

    // Clean up by closing the file and closing curl
    fclose($putData);
    curl_close($session);
```

Comment: Umm. `echo $jsonString`?!

Comment: use browsers developer tool and check the network for the request with header and payloads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your code according to the following...

```
$session = curl_init();

// your code ...
// you may need this option
// CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array("Content-type: application/json")

// getting results
$output = curl_exec($session);
$json = json_decode($output, true);
print_r($json);

// ...
```